# How to downsample input label in binary high resolution segmentation?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I am going to solve a binary high resolution segmentation problem. Positive pixels are marked as same value while negative pixels are all zero. The input image is scaled to 1/4 by bi-cubic interpolation.

After scaling, the pixel values of positive labels are not all the same. So how to process these label images to make it still a binary segmentation problem? Just set the pixels which are larger than 0 to positive or set the pixels which larger than a threshold to positive?

If the answer is the latter one, how to set the threshold?

Comment: Don't use bicubic interpolation if you don't want to generate new grey-levels. For a binary image (or a labeled image) use nearest neighbor interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not use built-in resize functions, such as zoom or imresize. Suppose you have a binary mask of size 225 * 225, then the central point is (113, 113), start from this central point, sub-sample the points in all four directions with equal steps,(like 4). And finally you will find you have 4 different sample ways, average them.